# How to generate single PDF of page that contained multiple highcharts in DIVs

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, highcharts

I am generating multiple report charts in a single page and need to convert the same page into pdf and image.

Is it possible to create pdf same as the HTML?

JavaScript and html codes are below:

```
    $('#containerBar').highcharts({


        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['National Lottery', 'Ready Steady Cook', 'Vicar of Dibley']
        },

        ........
```

`containerBar` is on div id in side the page there is numbers of div containing chart.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.HighCharts shows this exact example. It uses a javascript in page to extract the content of a div or multiple div elements to produce pdf.

Comment: but there is no code. i have need for code or any library that can impliment in zend 2.

Comment: You have to read at least a little.. there IS the code: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage

Comment: Both this and also my suggestion can be imlpemented in any framework as these are simple libraries

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working but generated pdf is not well formated. there is multiple charts in multiple DIVs and these DIVs are inside a main DIV. i am passing this main DIV to convert in pdf. the resultant pdf generate all charts in new pages and. As I don't have knowledge as you so I am unable to formate. –

Comment: We can help to troubleshoot if we can see it in some way. Link or fiddle or? Do the inside DIVs have page-break-before set? They do in that sample only because the charts are such that two plus a few paras would not fit on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, but i do not think it is possible with highcharts itself.

I think you need to use a 3rd party library to generate PDFs.
I use [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) for that. you simply set up the PHP library, and paste the geenrated HTML page. you can embed your charts using the [highcharts export server](http://export.highcharts.com)

It may be a little work, but it works.
By using only highcharts i doubt it is possible.

**UPDATE** - or you can simply use some automated generator like this one:
[pdfcrowd.com](http://pdfcrowd.com/)
you can simply post your html page there and get the PDF

Comment: I have need for code or any library that can be impliment in zend 2. if you can then please help me to provide the link or code

Comment: in the link i sent you, you can download mPDF, it can be used in any php framework, or maybe there is also a special version for zend. I am not familiard enough with zend help you here, but it surely IS possible and you can also find the code and examples online